# error related to array index

Tags: java, split

Below code has variable "name". This may contain first and last name or only first name.  This code checks if there is any white space in variable "name". If space exists, then it splits.

However, I am getting the "Error : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 at Space.main(Space.java:9)" during below cases

- If there is a white space before "Richard"
- If there is a white space after "Richard" without second word or second string.
- If I have two spaces after "Richard" then it will not save the name in lname variable.

How to resolve this error.

```
public class Space {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String name = "Richard  rinse ";
    if(name.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
        String[] temp;
        temp = name.split(" ");
        String fname = temp[0];
        String lname = temp[1];
        System.out.println(fname);
        System.out.println(lname);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Space does not exists");}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe that way:

```
public class Space {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name = "Richard  rinse ";
        String tname = name.trim().replace("/(\\s\\s+)/g", " ");
        String[] temp;
        temp = name.split(" ");
        String fname = (temp.length > 0) ? temp[0] : null;
        String lname = (temp.length > 1) ? temp[1] : null;
        if (fname != null) System.out.println(fname);
        if (lname != null) System.out.println(lname);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Space does not exists");
    }
}
```

Comment: change `name.trim().replace("/(\s\s+)/g", " ");` to `name.trim().replace("/(\\s\\s+)/g", " ");`. You didn't escape them.

Comment: @ krzysztof Your code along with Sri Harsha Chilakapati escape code, then it worked.  Thanks for all your help..

Comment: Here you go. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 3):

you have to split a string using "\s" like this

```
name.split("\\s+");
```

Comment: +1. I would add: because split receives a regular expression for finding separators, not a substring.

Comment: Regex should really be `\s+` otherwise it will fail when there is more than one white space character between words. Also, the string should be `trim`ed first.

Answer (score 1):

If there are two spaces temp[1] will be empty, given "Richard  rinse" the array is split this way

1 Richard

2

3 rinse

You should `trim()` the string and do something like

```
while(name.contains("  "))
    name=name.replace("  "," ");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] parts = name.trim().split("\\s+");

if (parts.length == 2) {
    // print names out
} else {
    // either less than 2 names or more than 2 names
}
```

`trim` removes leading and trailing whitespace as this lead to either leading or trailing empty strings in the array

the token to split on is a regular expression meaning any series of characters made up of one or more whitespace characters (space, tabs, etc...).

Answer (score -1):

To trim the white spaces, use this.

```
public String trimSpaces(String s){
    String str = "";
    boolean spacesOmitted = false;
    for (int i=0; i<s.length; i++){
        char ch = s.chatAt(i);
        if (ch!=' '){
            spacesOmitted = true;
        }
        if (spacesOmitted){
            str+=ch;
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

Then use the trimmed string in the place of name.

Comment: Trimming spaces is already part of the standard library, no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: This is an awful memory shatter (I mean those `str+=ch`). StringBuilder should be used instead of a String as str type.

Comment: Standard library is implemented on the JVM side. This needs some calls to the JNI.

Comment: And that's a good thing why? I was under the impression that calling JNI methods is expensive and should be avoided where possible.

Comment: Though this is reinventing the wheel, it will be faster than the JNI calls. And some say that the standard library work different based on platform.